# XGBoost feature_importances_ parameters gives a 0 valued vector

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, statistics

I have experimented `XGBClassifier()` with a large dataset of shape `[400000,93]`,
the data contains a lot of **NaN** values, so I have used imputation from **sklearn** package

```
imputer = Imputer()
imputed_x = imputer.fit_transform(data)
data = imputed_x
```

but the feature importance values look like this:

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Notice there is only a `1` and the rest are `0`. For this reason, the resulting metrics are:

```
precision: 1.0
recall: 1.0
accuracy: 1.0
traning_accuracy: 1.0
```

Why the model can't fit the data.

**Example code fragments**

```
model_xboost = XGBClassifier(max_depth=5, n_estimators=100)

#train
model_xboost.fit(train_data, train_labels)
print(model_xboost.feature_importances_)
```

Comment: you can see that one of your features takes the whole decision making of your model. Therefore, only one feature out of the whole list of feature_importance has the value 1 and the rest are 0. Try removing this feature and see how your model behave. Seems like this specific feature overfit your model

Comment: thank you very much @Flika205...

Comment: I'm curious to know if it actually solved your issue and how your model behave after dropping this feature

Comment: Maybe that feature is your class label that you accidentally put in X, or maybe something that corresponds to the classes, which in reality is computed after the class is known. You should not take such features.

Comment: @VivekKumar, you are absolutely right

Comment: @Flika205 , after removing high correlated features , the model give a feature list with its importance

Answer (score 0):

You have one feature that is fully correlated to the target, with correlation value `1.0`. That means you have trained your model with the target. You must remove it in training.

Answer (score 0):

From the feature importance, there is only a `1` and the rest are `0`. It looks as if you have included a column which is somewhat similar to the target column in the training data, thus resulting in that feature being perfectly correlated to the target!

For example I've come across a classification problem where I used the patient's background and medical parameters to predict whether or not the patient has cancer. There was 1 column called "data_source" which became the most significant. That's purely because patients who come from "XXX Cancer Hospital" will surely have cancer!

This is a good example of unintended data leakage.